# my code is Unable to fetch local image assets

Tags: flutter, flutter-assetimage

I'm super new to programming, I'm currently follow a book called 'Flutter Apprentice' but I stuck in this chapter.

I've followed everything what the book says, I've checked all of my code, everything seems okay, no error the red lines are showing, but the image not showing up. After the process of debugging was over, this line of code kept showing up.
highlighted parts
[image]

```
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load
package:flutter/…/services/asset_bundle.dart:237
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync
package:flutter/…/painting/image_provider.dart:668
<asynchronous suspension>
Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "assests/6.jpg")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#f67bf(), name: "assests/6.jpg", scale: 1.0)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Restarted application in 2 289ms.
```

my images details

[image]

part of my main.dart
[image]

recipe.dart

[image]

yaml

[image]

Comment: Have you assigned assets on `pubspec.yaml`

Comment: yes, I just added the picture

Comment: Did you try with rebuilding the app after adding assets?

Comment: Also try providing full path on assets for each image

Comment: ```assets/1.jpg ``` is not a full path?

Comment: I've done ```flutter clean``` once.

Comment: sorry I mean set full path on pubspec.yaml

Comment: Also It is necessary to rebuild the app after adding assets

Comment: I just add   - assets/1.jpg
    - assets/2.jpg
    - assets/3.jpg
    - assets/4.jpg
    - assets/5.jpg
    - assets/6.jpg  on pubspace.yaml stil not working

Comment: what do you mean by "rebuilding" the app?

Comment: stop the app, and run again.

Comment: I've done that for many times ：（

Comment: It looks like you have a typo - the error says `assests/6.jpg` - is that an extra 's' in there?

Comment: @RichardHeap My App is WORKING NOW!!!!! THANK you

Answer (score -1):

1. create new folder in the same path of Lib as "assets" the name of the folder
2. add this

   assets:

   - assets/

inside pubspec.yaml

3. add your images inside asstes folder